# stellar-horizon db size

Tags: stellar-core, horizon

maybe someone could help me.
I have a node with the config below:

```
CATCHUP_RECENT=362880           # approximately 3 weeks (5sec per ledger closing) - stellar
HISTORY_RETENTION_COUNT=362880  # approximately 3 weeks (5sec per ledger closing) - horizon
```

but my horizon db is growing, and has already reached 217 GB, the largest tables:

```
 public | history_operations   | table | 51 GB  | 
 public | history_transactions | table | 104 GB |
```

is it real size? is it possible to check what real settings it uses (via api)?

---

**UPDATE:**
It's still growing, even after manually cleaning up the size remains the same.

```
 Schema |               Name   |   Type   |    Size | 
--------+----------------------+----------+---------+
 public | history_operations   | table    | 72 GB   |
 public | history_transactions | table    | 145 GB  |

$ horizon db reap
INFO[2021-01-06T12:11:29.178Z] reaper: clearing  new_elder=33057597 pid=130
INFO[2021-01-06T12:11:33.830Z] reaper succeeded  new_elder=33057597 pid=130
```